# ZBar code scanner ntdll.dll error in delphi

Tags: delphi, zbar

I am trying to scan a image using ZBar and I am working from this code example : http://blog.freehand.com.ua/2013/03/zbar-reading-bar-codes-in-delphi.html

This is the code I currently have :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var zimage : zbar_image_t;
weirdVarArea : SIZE_T;
weirdVarBlob : PByte;
sym: zbar_symbol_t;
begin
  zimage := zbar_image_create;
  zbar_image_set_format(zimage, 'Y800');
  zbar_image_set_size(zimage, Image1.Picture.Width, Image1.Picture.Height);

  weirdVarArea := Image1.Picture.Width * Image1.Picture.Height;
  weirdVarBlob := GetMemory(weirdVarArea);
  zbar_image_set_data(zimage, weirdVarBlob, weirdVarArea, nil);

  zbar_process_image(processor, zimage);

  //  sym := zbar_image_first_symbol(zimage);
  //  ShowMessage(zbar_symbol_get_data(sym));
end;

end.
```

There is one button named "Button1" on the form as well as a image component named "Image1" with a qr code loaded into it.

When I run that code I get the error : `Access violation at address 77E57543 in module 'ntdll.dll'. Write of address 000000A4.`

The line causing the trouble is `zbar_process_image(processor, zimage);`

I am not sure how to proceed.

Thanks for your responce, Kobus

Comment: You get the error at which line?

Comment: Its the last one in that procedure. If I comment out the zbar_process_image there are no errors

Comment: What is `processor`, and what is it's value in the line you've marked? And have you checked both the parameters and values being passed to `zbar_image_set_data` in the line above (which is probably the line actually raising the exception)?

Comment: One thing this code is NOT doing that the original code DOES do is that this code is *NOT populating the blob with pixel data* before calling `zbar_process_image()`. So that might be why it is crashing.

Comment: There's a defect in your code. You should read the docs for this library and check each call. It looks like you aren't doing any error checking. Only Chuck Norris can neglect error checking. Likely one of the calls fails. How would you know? I suggest that you do some debugging. What debugging have you done? Probably you don't yet know how to debug, so it's time to learn. GetMemory is an odd function to call. GetMem would be more normal. Are you sure you have 8 bit pixels?

Comment: Also, `TImage` does not deal in Y800 encoded pixels. The original code was getting the image pixels from a file, and so it was probably a Y800 encoded file. So you need to use the correct image format for the pixels that you are going to be feeding into the processor.

Comment: Ken processor is a zbar_processor_t which was not set to a instance. I just fixed that thanks.

Remy how would I go about populating a "blob" with pixel data ? What is a blob? The image I am using is a TPngImage what do I need to parse in that case ?

Comment: David thanks I will use GetMem. This is the first time ive worked with dlls so I am not sure how I would debug any of this or what to even look for but I will try my best. I am checking out the C documentation for ZBar as I could not find any relating to delphi.

Comment: It's a C library, that's where the docs will be presented. Delphi is not the only language. Debug like anything else. Inspect the input and output and compare against expectations.

Comment: Ok so I used a bunch of asserts to check if everything has been assigned. It all seems to work now but it cant find the barcode. I dont know if I am actually assigning the ZBarImage data. I think that zimage is empty.

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger? Are you checking return values? Have you got the documentation handy?

Comment: Yes i am using this (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/api/) documentation but it doesnt really show how to get the image data into the Zbar image type.

Comment: @whos that's what the Q links to

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ok, my eyes need glasses :(

Answer (score 0):

> Access violation at address 77E57543 in module 'ntdll.dll'. Write of address 000000A4.

This is actually Windows issue. When you get this error, you must find out the restore point when the application was working properly and close Windows automatic updates to prevent the issue happens again. If you cannot solve the issue with this way, you should reinstall your Windows.